# Unexpected Permissions and Roles for a Member

Tags: permissions, plone, roles

I'm using the intranet workflow to manage a site and I've created folders that are "internally published". One of our users has the owner role even though they are a member.

When I visit {mysite}/myfolder/the_item/manage_reportUserPermissions?user={USERID}
their roles in the context of a private object are reported as:

```
Authenticated
Member
*Owner*
Reader
```

The **Owner role** is concerning here and I need guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue, I'm not sure why this users is inheriting or acquiring this role.

Other users with the Member role are fine, meaning they have the the following roles in the same context mentioned above:

```
Authenticated
Member
Reader
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumingly from what you describe, the user has created the item.

As default behaviour creators are set to be the owner of an item.

If the assumption is right, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: These are definitely folders owned by OTHER users, yet this specific user (so far only this user) who ONLY has the role of MEMBER, appears to be getting the owner role in the context of these folders.

Comment: It doesn't matter who owns the other folders or which role the user has, because the Owner-role is not being inherited, it is set by the system on an item's creation. It looks to me, that the user once had the 'Add'-permission, created the item and then was disgranted the 'Add'-permission again.

Comment: I really do want to rule out everything, then I'll accept (or not).

Comment: The topic is admittedly underdocumentated, but here is a nice article from Luca Fabbri about the Owner-role: http://blog.keul.it/2011/09/plone-security-and-workflows-when-rely.html And maybe it's good to know, that 'Anonymous/Authenticated/Owner' are exceptioned from the UI with purpose, to exclude that these attributes are accidently wrongly set and fallsifying their meaning and purpose.

Comment: For the sake of correctness, referring to my first comment: Owner-roles are inherited just as any other, I ment the very local assigment on creation, which is the one visible via `/manage_reportUserPermissions?user=[USERID]`.

Comment: Rule out everything with zopyx.plone.cassandra and don't forget to unlock the caps.